# JS Select Element After Inserting

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have function that get some data from API and then insert some dynamic content, includes `img` element with the class of `lazyLoad`, how can i select this image after the content gets inserted?

**API.js**

```
const spoonacular = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch?apiKey=c0c692d2b8be4e92a29883049789419b&includeNutrition=true.",
    {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }
  );

  const data = await response.json();

  data.results.forEach((e) => {
    const html = `
    <div class="dish" id="a${e.id}">
      <a href="recipe/${e.id}"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="dishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h2 class="dishTitle">
        ${e.title}
      </h2>
  </div>
    `;
    dishes.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
  });
};
```

I tried using `onload` :

**lazyLoading.js**

````
window.onload = function () {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll(".lazyLoad");
  console.log(images); // returns empty ```NodeList```
};
````

but it doesnt work, how to select it after it gets inserted? thanks in advance

Comment: You have to do it in the code that does `await spoonacular()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `document.createElement` rather than HTML strings, you can directly access each element before inserting them into the DOM.

```js
data.results.forEach(e => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'dish'; div.id = 'a' + e.id;
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = 'recipe/' + e.id;
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = e.image;
    img.className = 'dishImg lazyLoad';
    // do something else with img here
    a.append(img);
    const h2 = document.createElement('h2');
    h2.className = 'dishTitle';
    h2.textContent = e.title;
    div.append(a, h2);
    dishes.prepend(div);
});
```

You could also consider using a `<template>` to store this repeated fragment of elements. For example:

```html
<template id="dishTemplate">
    <div class="dish">
        <a><img alt="" class="dishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
        <h2 class="dishTitle"></h2>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
data.results.forEach(e => {
    const content = document.getElementById('dishTemplate').content.cloneNode(true);
    content.firstElementChild.id = 'a' + e.id;
    content.querySelector('a').href = 'recipe/' + e.id;
    const img = content.querySelector('img');
    img.src = e.image;
    // do something else with img here
    Object.assign(content.querySelector('h2'), {className: 'dishTitle', textContent: e.title});
    dishes.prepend(content);
});
```